# Estimate a linear regression with multiple penalties

Tags: references, lasso, regularization

I am considering estimating a linear model with multiple penalties. For example, to estimate equation (4.8) on page 60 of the [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS.pdf), we can solve the convex program
$$
\min \frac{1}{N} \lVert \mathbf{y} - \beta_0\mathbf{1}_N - X\beta - \sum_{j=1}^{J}Z_j^{\intercal}\theta_j \rVert^2 + \lambda_1\lVert \beta \rVert_1 + \lambda_2\sum_{j=1}^{J} \lVert \theta_j\rVert
$$
This is different from the sparse group lasso proposed by [Jerome Friedman et al](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ftp/sparse-grlasso.pdf). They imposed lasso and group lasso on the common regression coefficients. However, we want to impose two different penalties on the two parts of the model. Of course we can estimate the model through iterations in the computer, but I don't know how to handle more than one penalty at the same time.

I hope someone can **provide some relevant papers or other related literature** on this topic. I haven't found a helpful paper in this area. Thank you in advance!

***Note***: Maybe lasso-group lasso is not an appropriate example since group lasso reduces to the ordinary lasso when group size is 1 and we can estimate the model by the method of group lasso, by I want to know how to handle multiple penalty terms simultaneously in general case, such as SCAD, the elastic net and so on.

Comment: What kind of references are you looking for? You seem to know what you want to do, what you need a reference for?

Comment: @Tim Hi. I want to derive theoretical results in this setting, so I hope existing work will offer an outline of the proof.

Comment: Proof for what?

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your attention. Take the consistency of slope as an example. In the ordinary lasso regression setting, we can show that the lasso estimator, beta hat, is consistent. If we add other qualitative factors into the model, and  impose additional group lasso penalty on the theta, then how to prove the consistency of beta?

Comment: But notice that for lasso there is the same penalty for all the parameters. Here you would like proof that for any combination of the parameters you can apply arbitrary L1 or L2 penalties and the model would be consistent..?

Comment: @Tim yes. just like the linear model with both quantitative and qualitative predictors, and impose lasso (or SCAD and so on) to quantitative predictors, impose group lasso to qualitative factors. How to show that the regression coefficients of qualitative predictors are consistent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128203/discussion-between-hj-liang-and-tim).